# Changing URL in NodeJS only

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following segment of code in my server callback:

```
switch (request.url) {
    case "/somescript" :
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
        response.write(somescript);
        break;      
    default :
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"});
        response.write(html);
}
response.end();
```

When I run the server, when I enter this:

```
localhost:3000
```

on the browser, how can I have it change automatically to:

```
localhost:3000/changed
```

Only using Node.js (in my default section of the switch statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `response.writeHead(301, {"Location": "/changed"});`  to default.

```
switch (request.url) {
    case "/somescript" :
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
        response.write(somescript);
        break;      
    case "/changed" :
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"});
        response.write(changedhtml);
        break;
    default :
        response.writeHead(301, {"Location": "/changed"});`
}
response.end();
```

Comment: Then I get the error "The localhost page isn’t working, localhost redirected you too many times."

Comment: Well, you have to add `case "/changed":` too to prevent it.

Comment: I tried that initially and got a different error:
The webpage at http://localhost:3000/changed might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING